# Supertable or Neo for nested Matrices and compatibility with Craft 4

Tags: matrix, plugin-supertable, plugin-neo, craft4

I typically avoid using Supertable or Neo because I don't want the extra dependency going forward. However I'm in a project where I needed nested matrices.

I know that in C4 nested matrices will be possible and that there is likely to be a migration script for that (according to what I remember from dotall2019). That being the case which plugin is recommended Supertable or Neo?

Will they both have a migration path to Native?

Answer (score 1):

In reply. In a tweet from Brandon... Neo will get a direct upgrade path to matrix.
https://twitter.com/brandonkelly/status/1114144432243265536?s=19

That being said. I used supertable more recently.